# Structure of an iframe

Tags: html, url, iframe

I have a question about iframe.

For iframe, we normally see:

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com" />
```

Could we put IP address instead? (for example)

```
<iframe src="http://192.142.1.1" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but the syntax is `<iframe src="http://google.com"></iframe>`, or `<iframe src="http://192.142.1.1"></iframe>`.

Comment: It's OK, happy to help :)

Comment: If my answer helped, vote me up using the arrows next to my answer, and accept by clicking the tick.

Comment: Once I get enough reputation, I will gladly vote your answer.